# Cannot remigrate migration after migration rollback Laravel 5.2

Tags: migration, laravel-5

Good day, I'm new to laravel I was doing a migration rollback and it was successfully done

> Rolled back: 2018_02_22_172102_adding_fk_constrains_products_to_product_types_and_service_sub_types_table

But when I try to re-migrate I encountered this error below. BTW I don't want to drop the column because it already existed and I don't want to lose the existing data in that column. I only want to add constraint between those tables

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>       SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1022 Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-2fc8_17c' (SQL: alter table `products` add constraint `products_product_type_id_foreign`
>       foreign key (`product_type_id`) references `product_types` (`id`) on update cascade)
>
> [PDOException]
>       SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1022 Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-2fc8_17c'

```
Table     Non_unique  Key_name                            Seq_in_index  Column_name
--------  ----------  ----------------------------------  ------------  -------------------
products           0  PRIMARY                                        1  id             
products           1  products_product_type_id_index                 1  product_type_id  
products           1  products_service_sub_type_id_index             1  service_sub_type_id
```

this my migration code

```
public function up()
{

    Schema::table('products',function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->integer('product_type_id')->unsigned()->index()->change();
        $table->foreign('product_type_id')->references('id')->on('product_types')->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->integer('service_sub_type_id')->nullable()->unsigned()->index()->change();
        $table->foreign('service_sub_type_id')->references('id')->on('service_sub_types')->onUpdate('cascade');

    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{

    Schema::table('products', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->dropForeign(['product_type_id']);
        $table->dropForeign(['service_sub_type_id']);
    });

}
```

Comment: you might need to check your MySQL database to see if the the foreign key actually exist, else you can try to use Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();

Comment: Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints(); I added this code in my down() method but the error still persist.

Comment: so did the key/column actually exist in your DB currently?

Comment: Yeah. it exist in my DB. I added the result of this query in my updated question SHOW INDEXES FROM `products`;

Comment: well you see the issue is that the key name is actually 'products_product_type_id_index', laravel naming convention for dropping foreign key is to use _foreign suffix, so in your case it should be product_type_id_foreign

Comment: I already tried to use products_product_type_id_index but still no luck

Comment: in your case it should be $table->dropForeign('product_type_id_foreign');

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'product_type_id_foreign'; check that column/key exists sitll no luck

Comment: another way from the documentation is parse the array value $table->dropForeign(['product_type_id']);

Comment: I also did that but still no luck. I already tested all in the documentation before I post a question here. I'm so confused what is the real problem with my down method

Comment: kinda strange that method doesn't work, what if you just drop the column instead with $table->dropColumn('product_type_id');

Comment: is it possible to drop a column without dropping the FK constraints? If possible I cant do that because the column data will be lost... It should be working but I don't know why it's not. :(

Comment: well since the migration involves creating those 2 columns, it's only natural that those are deleted/drop on rollback, unless that's not what you have in mind

Comment: that column already exist in the first place I just altered that column to became FK by using this line of code $table->integer('product_type_id')->unsigned()->index()->change();
            $table->foreign('product_type_id')->references('id')->on('product_types')->onUpdate('cascade');

I only want to drop the FK not the column

Comment: I see, what exactly is your error output when running $table->dropForeign(['product_type_id']); ?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP '[product_type_id]'; check that column/key exists (SQL: alter table products drop foreign key product_type_id)

Comment: well you need to put the [] bracket out of the 'product_type_id', it's an array, ['product_type_id'] instead of  '[product_type_id]'

Comment: it works, but the problem is when e remigrate it will occur another error. ill update my question

Comment: That normally happens when you already have the same foreign key names in the DB, recheck your DB again to see if the previous ones had been removed, else try to change the key names

Comment: so the down method is useless? this line of code         $table->dropForeign(['product_type_id']);
        $table->dropForeign(['service_sub_type_id']);? I already drop the FK of that column so it should be ok to add it again as a FK

Comment: what's in your key/index list now, after you drop the FK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just remove the following code in my migration

> $table->integer('product_type_id')->unsigned()->index()->change();
>
> $table->integer('service_sub_type_id')->nullable()->unsigned()->index()->change();

```
public function up()
{

   Schema::table('products',function (Blueprint $table){
      //$table->integer('product_type_id')->unsigned()->index()->change();
      $table->foreign('product_type_id')->references('id')->on('product_types')->onUpdate('cascade');

      //$table->integer('service_sub_type_id')->nullable()->unsigned()->index()->change();
      $table->foreign('service_sub_type_id')->references('id')->on('service_sub_types')->onUpdate('cascade');

});
}
```

when I re migrate it was successfully migrated..

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking for a solution, add this code to the down() method.

```
public function down()
{

    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');

    Schema::table('products', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->dropForeign(['product_type_id']);
        $table->dropForeign(['service_sub_type_id']);
    });

    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');

}
```